# Doctrine event post_persist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I created an event like this:

service.yml

```
AccountManager:
    class: %AccountManager.class%
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

my Subscriber

```
class AccountManager implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'postPersist',
            'postUpdate',
        );
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->index($args);
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->index($args);
    }

    public function index(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager(); //BREAKPOINT

        if ($entity instanceof User) {

            echo $entity;
        }
    }
}
```

If i see my code where i added breakpoint, `$entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();` i don't find new user in my Database. After all I Have the new user in Database.

From documentation doctrine, i can read

> postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the
>   entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database
>   insert operations. Generated primary key values are available in the
>   postPersist event.

My questions are

- Why I don't have new user in my Database during my Event?
- I don't understand the main difference between Listener/Subscriber. In this case,what is the better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why I don't have new user in my Database during my Event?

That's because DB transaction isn't commited at that time. If you take a look at a hearth of Doctrine, [`UnitOfWork::commit()` function](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L312) you'll see that in your case following operations are performed:

1. Dispatch `preFlush` event.
2. Dispatch `onFlush` event.
3. Open DB transaction.
4. Call `executeInserts()`

   1. Performs actual `INSERT`s.
   2. Dispatch `postPersist` event.
5. Commit the transaction. That's the moment when your data becamse visible to others (transactions) in RDBMS.
6. Dispatch `postFlush` event.

> I don't understand the main difference between Listener/Subscriber. In this case,what is the better?

They are pretty much two different ways to achieve exactly the same. In case of EventListeners you configure them from the outside world, pseudocode:

```
$ed = new EventDispatcher();
$ed->addListener('some.event', $myObject, 'myMethod'); // $myObject::myMethod listens
                                                       // to some.event

$ed->addSubscriber($myObject); // ask $myObject for events it wants to listen to

// EventDispatcher::addSubscriber could look like this

function addSubscriber(EventSubscriber $object) {
    foreach ($object->getSubscribedEvents() as $event => $method) {
        $this->addListener($event, $object, $method);
    }
}
```

I would say that both of them are equal in terms of "which one is better" in this case.

Comment: Perfect Crozin ! this is what I was Looking for